# Why adding a few rows of constraints can dramatically slow down the running time of MIP optimization?

Tags: optimization, computational-complexity, mixed-integer-programming

I am working on a linear mixed-integer programming (MIP) optimization problem. Let's say the constraint can be denoted as $Ax\leq b$, where A is the constraint matrix.

Previously, A has a dimension roughly 1500 * 1500, and the COIN-OR CBC solver [An open-source MIP solver](https://projects.coin-or.org/Cbc) only runs about 2 min to solve the problem. Now I need to add a new type constraint, which is only about 70 rows and yields A to be a 1570 * 1500 matrix. However, in this case, it runs about 5 hours to obtain a solution.

I understand that MIP is NP-hard and the complexity cannot simply be denoted in terms of number of constraints/variables. But this result is still surprising to me. Any suggestion? Use a commercial solver? Thanks.

**Appendix**: For those who are interested, the new type constraint I added is a rolling constraint to limit the number of starts per period. Here is a simple example: Suppose there are 3 kinds of appointments A, B and C, either of them can only start at 8:00, 8:30, or 9:00. The constraint is that within a 30min window ($\leq$30min), at most one appointment can start. The matrix A is like
$$M=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
   8:00 & 8:30 & 9:00 & 8:00 & 8:30 & 9:00 & 8:00 & 8:30 & 9:00\\
   1 & 1 & 0 &  1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 
  \end{array} } \right].$$
Variables are [# of A scheduled at 8:00, # of A scheduled at 8:30, # of A scheduled at 9:00, # of B scheduled at 8:00, ...]. Right hand side are [1,1] in this case.

Comment: The order of constraints can also sometimes have an impact on a solver's performance. If you add the new constraints in a different position in the matrix, the solution times can also in- or decrease.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really not surprising that adding even one constraint can make a problem much harder. Consider a problem with nonnegative variables where $(0,\ldots,0)$ is feasible and the objective (to be minimized) has positive coefficients.  Then
$(0,\ldots,0)$ is the unique optimal solution, and your MIP solver should find it
almost instantly.  But add the constraint $\sum_i x_i \ge 100$, and things are
likely to become much more interesting.

Comment: I understand your point. What I think is that it already has 1500 rows which involves lots of constraints. Adding one new constraint (70 rows) really couldn't make it 100 times harder...

Comment: Actually, it could (and apparently did) make the problem much harder. I assume that the solution previously found violates some of the new constraints. So an easy to find (or easily proved optimal) solution is off the table now. Many things could be in play here. It might be informative to look at the node log and see how much time is spent finding the optimal solution and how much time is spent proving its optimality.